# Returning itself in property

Tags: c#, .net

I've start using following method grouping to make my code more readable:

```
public interface IUserMethodGroup
{
   void SomeMethodOne();
   String SomeMethodTwo();
}

//File MainClass.Users.cs
public partial class MainClass : IUserMethodGroup
{
   void IUserMethodGroup.SomeMethodOne(){ //some code }
   String IUserMethodGroup.SomeMethodTwo(){ return "some str";}
}

//File MainClass.cs
public partial class MainClass
{
    //HOW ABOUT PERFORMANCE?
    public IUserMethodGroup UserHandle {get { return this; } }       
}
```

Does it has big impact on performance?

Edit 1

This allow me to do that:

```
class ConsumerClass
{
   public void Method()
   {
      MainClass mc = new MainClass();

      mc.UserHandle.SomeMethodOne();

      //@ vc 74:
      //Interface has to be explicitly, otherwise it will be:
      ms.SomeMethodOne(); //grouping lost...
    }
}
```

@adelphus:
Consider I have 5 similar properties (method groups). Every time I want to use some method from group I asking class to return itself. Does it be much slower compared to implementing without groups?

Comment: Compared to what...?

Comment: Whatever impact it may or may not have, it is almost certainly negligible compared to the real bottlenecks of your app

Comment: If your question is 'do partial classes create performance issues?' then the answer is no, the framework has no idea your class is partial. It's only a C# compiler thing so the performance will be similar to having a non partial class.

Comment: @arche89 was the explicit interface implementation intended? Otherwise if you remove the IUserMethodGroup prefix from the methods in MainClass, you'll be able to invoke them without having to have a IUserMethodGroup reference.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I edited post to answer your questions. I hope that my question is more clear now.

Comment: Wait, you're explicitly using interfaces to make sure your gigantic classes are more manageable? Why? If you have different domains handled by the same class, separate it into multiple classes. "Hiding" the complexity like this doesn't help you much, it still means the classes responsibility is way too broad - every method still has the full scope of the class. The performance impact of having a property that returns `this` is negligible compared even to the fact that you now have to make a virtual method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every time I want to use some method from group I asking class to return itself. Does it be much slower compared to implementing without groups?

No.  Returning `this` in a read-only property should just be one line of IL code.  In fact is may even be inlined by the JIT optimizer.

The bigger question is why do you have so many methods on one class?  Having so many methods that they need to be "organized" by explicit interface implementations smells like you have a class that is doing too much.

One thing this design *does* allow is for you to have *different* classes that implement the different "groups".  Your single class then becomes an aggregator that combines the functionality of several different interfaces into a single class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using it for example in DbContext implementation. Grouping common sets: Address(Streets, Cities, Postal Codes, Regions, Districts), Account(Groups, Users, Roles...) etc. It is more convenient for me.